# Honda Civic violent shaking when put into reverse or drive gears

Tags: noise, transmission, automatic-transmission, civic, shaking

I Recently picked up a 2008 Civic EX sedan with the 5-speed automatic. Had it up for for a day or so fixing up the air suspension and replacing the power steering fluid and engine oil. I took it down from the jack stands today and when I put it into reverse to back it out of my garage, the front end started vibrating violently. Same when I put it into drive. It does this when in gear and stationary. It does not do this when in park or neutral. It was not doing this two days prior when I pulled it into my garage. I did nothing to the transmission. What should I be looking for? Could it be a bad transmission mount? I don’t think the transmission would all of sudden take a crap like that when it was fine just days ago!

I have attached a link to a video of the problem:

[Honda Civic Violent Shaking Video](https://imgur.com/a/7XCkRkL)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of coincidence.  I think it's more likely that something you did created this problem.  Of the things you listed, the air suspension looks suspicious.  I'd be checking that system.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you are feeling the vibration when it is in neutral/park, it's something going on with the engine. I'd venture to bet it may be missing on one cylinder ... something the computer isn't picking up. You could check exhaust manifold temps right where it comes out of the head to see if one is lower than others. Just a thought.

Comment: The vibration only occurs when in reverse and drive. It is fine in park and neutral.

Comment: Wow, completely misread that ... sorry.

Comment: First thing to check is the motor\transmission mounts.

Comment: The main engine mount seems fine, and so do the two torque strut mounts, but the transmission mount may be bad. I can’t really tell just by looking at it because it’s pretty deep into the engine bay